# Chart only a subsection of data in my table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table and I want to show only a part of that data as a chart.

This is my data

```
pets       age
coco       3
rover      3
clifford   8
rugrat     7
doug       1
```

I want to make a chart that shows pets on the x-axis and age on the y-axis.

Importantly, I want to show data for pets that are at least four years old (clifford and rugrat).

In my use case, I cannot delete those rows from my table because it would adversely affect other tables in my worksheet. I would also rather avoid pivot tables. My band-aid fix is to select the data and manually select, in this example, clifford and rugrat.

Comment: Can you simply use another table (with the pets and lookup) to pull out what you want to plot?

Comment: I'd rather not clutter my worksheet because I have this problem with numerous tables. I have a big table where I'm okay with extra categories and then a smaller table that pulls from the big one. Maybe another option is to make sure that the smaller table only has values that meets the criteria

Comment: I could do it by hand, but the underlying data updates and so categories that sometimes do not meet the filter might later on meet the conditions for that filter

Comment: If I understand the above 2 comments, then I think we're saying the same thing. :) But perhaps you could expand your OP to clarify the fuller conditions / scenario?

Comment: When you filter your base data then hidden rows should not be visible in the chart - do you know this option: Ribbon > Select Data -> Hidden and Empty Cells (a button at bottom left) -> uncheck Show data in hidden rows and columns.

Comment: @Cauder, Are you looking for some **VBA** code, is it Okay?

Comment: @AziMez, VBA code is okay. Ike, does that mean that my table will be filtered but other tables in the same row on the sheet will not be filtered?

Comment: A filter hides always the entire row - so when you multiple, side-by-side-tables filter of one table will affect the visible rows of the other tables, and by that presumably the charts as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned you prefer to avoid pivot tables. This solution utilizes pivot charts, NOT pivot tables.

1. Click anywhere in the table and go to insert->pivot chart
2. (Optional) In the Create PivotChart menu, select the check box to Add this data to the Data Model. This will prevent a Pivot Table from being created in the workbook.
   [image]
3. Drag Age into the values section and Pets into the Axis (Categories) section.
   [image]
4. Click the dropdown button on the Pets field and add a value filter. In this case you want the sum of age to be greater than 4. (Alternatively, you can use the Pets button on the pivot chart.)

[image]
[image]

Below is the final product. You may wish to adjust the y-axis, add titles, etc. from here.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**In Case you have Office 365, Try this:**

Let assume that the following:

- "pets" is on column A
- "age"  is on column B
- You are Working in "Sheet5"
- File Name is Book2

From the name Manager, create a named range called "Titles" and with value as:

> =FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet5!$A$2:"&"$A$"&COUNTA(Sheet5!$A:$A)),INDIRECT("Sheet5!$B$2:"&"$B$"&COUNTA(Sheet5!$B:$B))>4)

From the name Manager, create another named range called "Values" and with value as:

> =FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet5!$B$2:"&"$B$"&COUNTA(Sheet5!$B:$B)),INDIRECT("Sheet5!$B$2:"&"$B$"&COUNTA(Sheet5!$B:$B))>4)

For Chart do the below:

1. Insert the chart type you need **not based on the data in Column A & B** and then
2. Click on the chart
3. From the Chart Design Tab click on "Select Data"
4. Under "Legend Entries (Series)" click "Add"
5. In The "Series Value" Box type Book2!Values (Values is the named range created before)
6. Under "Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels" click "Edit"
7. In The "Axis label range" Box type Book2!Titles (Titles is the named range created before)

Comment: If the data is already in an Excel table, you could probably simplify the formulas with something like `=FILTER(Table1[Age],Table1[Age]>4)`. and `=FILTER(Table1[Pets],Table1[Age]>4)`. Either way, nice solution.